# How to call rest end point

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey

I have been working through a tutorial I found online - I am however having a couple of issues with being able to call my rest end point from a browser as I am unsure of the URL that needs to be used - I keep getting 404 errors.

I am not sure if i am missing some config or what not but my server seems to start fine in eclipse. Please would it be possible for someone to provide some help.

Thanks

**Rest end point**

```
@Path("/jersey-hello")
public class JerseyResource
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JerseyResource.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Inject
    private DateTimeService timeService;

    public JerseyResource()
    {
        LOGGER.info("HelloWorldResource()");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("hi")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello()
    {
        return String.format("%s: %s", timeService.getDateTime(), greetingService.greet("world"));
    }
}
```

**Register resource configs**

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig
{
    public MyApplication()
    {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        register(JerseyResource.class);
        register(SpringSingletonResource.class);
        register(SpringRequestResource.class);
        register(CustomExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <module-name>restprj</module-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.test.demo.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**application-context**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="greetingService"
        class="com.rest.test.demo.GreetingServiceImpl" />

    <bean class="com.rest.test.demo.DateTimeService"
        scope="request" />

    <bean
        class="com.rest.test.demo.SpringSingletonResource" />

    <bean
        class="com.rest.test.demo.SpringRequestResource"
        scope="request" />

    <bean
        class="com.rest.test.demo.CustomExceptionMapper" />
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.rest.test</groupId>

    <artifactId>helloworld-spring-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>jersey-examples-helloworld-spring-webapp</name>

    <description>Spring 3 Integration Jersey Example</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.jaxrs.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.8.v20121106</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <descriptor>/src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**server startup**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.rest.test:helloworld-spring-webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 66, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
Downloading: http://salnexus/nexus/content/groups/salerio/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://salnexus/nexus/content/groups/salerio/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (710 B at 3.8 KB/sec)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jersey-examples-helloworld-spring-webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.8.v20121106:run (default-cli) @ helloworld-spring-webapp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ helloworld-spring-webapp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ helloworld-spring-webapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ helloworld-spring-webapp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev-rl\hg\restprj\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helloworld-spring-webapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.8.v20121106:run (default-cli) @ helloworld-spring-webapp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.8.v20121106:run (default-cli) @ helloworld-spring-webapp ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: jersey-examples-helloworld-spring-webapp
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Defaulting to C:\dev-rl\hg\restprj\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\dev-rl\hg\restprj\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\dev-rl\hg\restprj\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = /src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\dev-rl\hg\restprj\src\main\webapp
2016-08-12 11:18:10.083:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.8.v20121106
2016-08-12 11:18:10.603:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2016-08-12 11:18:10.807:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/dev-rl/hg/restprj/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/dev-rl/hg/restprj/src/main/webapp/
2016-08-12 11:18:10.858:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiest, if you move everything to the expected defaults folders.

webapp folder from `src/main/resources/webapp` to `src/main/webapp`.

I renamed `application-context.xml` to `src/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` and removed the `context-param` in **web.xml**.

I put a simple `index.html` with the content "hello" into `src/webapp/index.html`.

I removed the configuration tag from the jetty plugin in **pom.xml**.

After that I did `mvn jetty:run`. The I was able to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/helloworld-spring-webapp/jersey-hello - results in HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /helloworld-spring-webapp/jersey-hello. Reason:

    Not Found

Comment: @Biscuit128 what app server are you using and how are you deploying the app?

Comment: im using an embedded jetty instance

Comment: i wonder if the path in my jetty plugin in the pom is incorrect - /src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: you probably need to set the context path, see here http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html#setting-context-path

Comment: @Biscuit128 you could try to add <dumpOnStart>true</dumpOnStart> to the jetty plugin config section. Maybe this will give you more info.

Comment: added this output to the original message

Comment: @Biscuit128 I edited my answer. See above. Try moving everything to the default locations and remove the config. Embedded jetty doesn't add any context root, so you should be able to access you test with `http://localhost:8080/jersey-hello`. See if you can access a sample index.html first. The you know the deployment worked.

Comment: thanks so much for the help - this is becoming seriously frustrating! After making your changes i still get the same error when using the url provided

Comment: @Biscuit128 http://localhost:8080 works ok, right? Did you add a simple index.html page and try http://localhost:8080/index.html ? Can you provide an updated log from mvn jetty:run ? If you put a zip file of the complete project somewhere, I might be able to have a look at the problem.

Comment: almost certain i followed your instructions to the letter - i have added a copy of my project as a zip folder here - http://www.filedropper.com/restprj - i did add the sample index.html page yes

Comment: your zip file doesn't include src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml and src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationConfig.xml

Comment: You said move it to src/webapp not src/main/webapp - sorry if i have misubderstood

Comment: @Biscuit128 Edit, my mistake. I moved src/webapp to src/main/webapp, followed by mvn jetty:run. Then `localhost:8080/index.html` works, as well as `localhost:8080/jersey-hello/hi`

Comment: this worked - thank you so much for all of your help